# Lazy load component populated by graphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I have a cards component that I use in my index page that takes data from a graphQL query like this :

```js
data.allStrapiArticle.nodes.map(article => {
            return (
              <Card
                id={article.id}
                title={article.title}
                category={article.categories}
                author={article.author.name}
                content={article.content}
                imgUrl={article.cover.publicURL}
                date={article.created_at}
                slug={article.slug}
              />
            )
          })
```

however, this will load all the article cards. I want to load only 3 cards first and when the user scrolls past the third one it will load 3 more until it reaches a maximum of 12.

How can I do this? I've tried using intersection observer with vanilla js but it didn't work:

```js
let numberToLoad = 3
   function loadCards() {
    numberToLoad += 3
    data.allStrapiArticle.nodes.slice(0, numberToLoad).map(article => {
      return (
        <Card
          id={article.id}
          title={article.title}
          category={article.categories}
          author={article.author.name}
          content={article.content}
          imgUrl={article.cover.publicURL}
          date={article.created_at}
          slug={article.slug}
        />
      )
    })
  }
  let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        loadCards()
        observer.unobserve(entry.target)
      }
    })
  })
  document.querySelectorAll(".card").forEach(card => {
    observer.observe(card)
  })
```

Comment: Do you handle the scrolling already? If yes, please paste the code to help us answer your question.

Comment: No, I don't. I mean, I got the IntersectionObserver working but that's all. I will add that code to the post